# C5.0 algorithm not working due to logical factor, solutions?

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, c5.0

This question has been asked before, however it was not answered in a way that solved my problem. The question was also slightly different.

I am trying to build a decision tree model using the c5 package. I am trying to predict if MMA fighters have championship potential (this is a logical factor with 2 levels yes/no).

Originally this column was a boolean but i converted it to a factor using

```
fighters_clean$championship_potential <- as.factor(fighters_clean$championship_potential)
table(fighters_clean$championship_potential)
#Rename binary outcome
fighters_clean$championship_potential <- factor(fighters_clean$championship_potential, 
                                                levels = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), labels = c("YES", "NO"))
```

on my data frame it says "Factor with 2 levels" which should work as the classifier for a c5 decision tree, however I keep getting this error message.

```
Error in UseMethod("QuinlanAttributes") : 
  no applicable method for 'QuinlanAttributes' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

The code for my model is below.

```
#Lets use a decision tree to see what fighters have that championship potential 
table(fighters_clean$championship_potential)
#FALSE  TRUE 
#2578   602 

#create test and training data 
#set seed alters the random number generator so that it is random but repeatable, the number is arbitrary.
set.seed(123)
Tree_training <- sample(3187, 2868)
str(Tree_training)

#So what this does is it creates a vector of 2868 random integers. 
#We use this vector to split our data into training and test data
#it should be a representative 90/10 split. 

Tree_Train <- fighters_clean[Tree_training, ]
Tree_Test <- fighters_clean[-Tree_training, ]

#That worked, sweet. 
#Now lets see if they are representative. 
#Should be even number of champ potential in both data sets, 

prop.table(table(Tree_Train$championship_potential))
prop.table(table(Tree_Test$championship_potential))

#awesome so thats a perfect split, with each data set having 18% champions. 
#C5 is a commercial software for decision tree models that is built into R
#We will use this to build a decision tree. 
str(Tree_Train)

'data.frame':   2868 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ name                  : chr  "Jesse Juarez" "Milton Vieira" "Joey Gomez" "Gilbert Smith" ...
 $ SLpM                  : num  1.71 1.13 2.93 1.09 5.92 0 0 1.2 0 2.11 ...
 $ Str_Acc               : num  48 35 35 41 51 0 0 33 0 50 ...
 $ SApM                  : num  2.87 2.36 4.03 2.73 3.6 0 0 1.73 0 1.89 ...
 $ Str_Def               : num  52 48 53 35 55 0 0 73 0 63 ...
 $ TD_Avg                : num  2.69 2.67 1.15 3.51 0.44 0 0 0 0 0.19 ...
 $ TD_Acc                : num  33 53 37 60 33 0 0 0 0 40 ...
 $ TD_Def                : num  50 12 50 0 70 0 0 50 0 78 ...
 $ Sub_Avg               : num  0 0.7 0 1.2 0.4 0 0 0 0 0.3 ...
 $ Win_percentage        : num  0.667 0.565 0.875 0.714 0.8 ...
 $ championship_potential: Factor w/ 2 levels "YES","NO": 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ contender             : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...


library(C50)
DTModel <- C5.0(Tree_Train [-11], Tree_Train$championship_potential, trials = 1, costs = NULL)
```

Comment: You aren't showing us what you did.  After setting the labels, the table would not have `TRUE`, `FALSE`, it would have `YES` and `NO`.  So you didn't run the conversion, or undid it later.  That's why you're getting the complaint about a logical variable.

Comment: See updated question. I don't believe I undid it